# Programing with certificates in java

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

I am programing a homework in Java where I have to use SSL certificates. I would like to know if there is any way to get your own name (like the method

> ((SSLSocket) socket).getSession().getPeerPrincipal().getName();

but that it gives you YOUR name and not the peer's one). I know I need to change .getPeerPrinciple(), but I cannot find to what I have to change it (since most of the time it is used to identify yourself to other people.

Comment: The server has no name in that sense. What information would you like to have?

Comment: I need name of user in client's code.

Comment: I don't think that's giving you the name you seek but `getLocalPrincipal()` would be opposite of the peer principal

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to find. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The exact opposite is

```
((SSLSocket) socket).getSession().getLocalPrincipal().getName();
```

But there is only a local principal on the client side when client certificates are involved. The principal is otherwise `null`.